# How to handle refresh token expiration in OkHttp?

Tags: okhttp

I want to navigate to login view when refresh token expires. How can i handle this case using **OkHttp** in android. Server responds with error code **403 forbidden** when refresh token expires. Are there any ways to handle refresh token expiration case?